# CSOM CAML query returning every item in the list

Tags: caml-query, csom, camlviewfields

I'm trying to retrieve a list of items where some conditions are applied but when I run my web page it returns all records. basically this query checks whether any record with these conditions exist or not, if exist function will validate and will not create a new item and vice versa

Here's what my CAML query looks like:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>28</Value></Eq>
         <And>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name='WorkflowStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Rejected</Value></Neq> 
            <And>    
                <Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>173</Value></Neq>              
                <And>
                    <Geq><FieldRef Name='HRLastDayOfLeave'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2015-10-9</Value></Geq>
                    <Leq><FieldRef Name='HRFirstDayOfLeave'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2015-10-8</Value></Leq>
                </And>
           </And>
       </And>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Build your CAML query using this tool http://www.u2u.be/Software

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your query in **View** tag. It will retrieve filter data only.

I.e.

```
<View><Query>
      <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>28</Value></Eq>
            <And>
                <Neq><FieldRef Name='WorkflowStatus'/><Value Type='Text'>Rejected</Value></Neq> 
                <And>    
                    <Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>173</Value></Neq>  
                    <And>
                        <Geq><FieldRef Name='HRLastDayOfLeave'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2015-10-9</Value></Geq>
                        <Leq><FieldRef Name='HRFirstDayOfLeave'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2015-10-8</Value></Leq>
                    </And>
                </And> 
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>
 </Query></View>
```